# AngularJS in a professional environment

Tags: angularjs

1. Can you call an Angularjs app a single page angular application if while it's built/setup in angular, but then you might use jQuery for a carousel image or jQuery for fade effects or something like this added to the site that isn't angular. Would it technically be a single page angular application if jQuery or something else is incorporated in the app? I'm asking because of when I see job listings for single page applications, I want to make sure I fully understand the underlying meaning of a single page application
2. Also wouldn't it technically not be a single page if ng-src routed to another .html file and the page refreshed to do so as opposed to using routeprovider and locationprovider to make it appear without refreshing via ng-view?

Comment: I would suggest you are getting far to granular if reason for asking is related to job posts

Comment: Agreed - although it's great to hone your understanding in this manner, the simple answer is that it depends. You're not breaking any rules either way, providing there is a good reason for doing it. The fact that you're understanding this stuff anyway says to me you'd be able to surface those reasons without any problem.

Comment: Normally a single page application loads content dynamically which is done by angular (and jquery). You have one html-file and content is presented dynamical. I can not answer whether it is a singl-page-application if you use ng-src. If you have a Job offer which needs a single-page app, you should evaluate the conditions with the Provider of the offer. Here is a link to a Website where SPA is declared: http://singlepageappbook.com/goal.html

Answer (score 1):

1. That may come as a surprise to you, but Angular have its own jQuery subset implementation called [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). As long as you load a single HTML page and dynamically update its contents instead of navigating away, it is an SPA regardless of javascript libraries in use.
2. That's kind of opinion-based, but I would call it a non-SPA since it causes a refresh (for something other than, say, updating to a newly-deployed version.)